# Wraps a string to a specific item (CSS display: flex;)

Tags: css

SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH

Typeset in the calendar with CSS display:flex; properties, faced with a means of CSS to move to a new line after the seventh element.

```
<div class="calendar">
   <div class="days">
      <a href="#">01</a>
      <a href="#">01</a>
      ...
      <a href="#">30</a>
      <a href="#">31</a>
   </div>
</div>

.calendar .days {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jeen/dhvzp6wm/2/).

Comment: I was helped to find a solution, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dhvzp6wm/9/